# access application located in the server directly from pc

Tags: windows-7, webserver

I have an application inside server and to access this application I have to open remote desktop connection and then log in to the server to open the application, and I need to know if its possible to create shortcut in my PC so that it can open the application located in the server directly without the need to open remote desktop connection

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the server, you could share the `program files` directory or only the folder where the program is installed and try to launch it by going to `\\server\\share name`. If you don't have control then there's really nothing you can do.

Depending on what program it is. If you have info for that program that are stored locally on the server then if you launch the program via shared folder then the program will launch looking for info stored on YOUR computer and not the server's. One of our clients where i work has a similar scenario where they have to RDP in to use the program.